# SQL Server 2012 Retrieving Attributes for 2 Columns of a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables.

**Highschooler**

[image]

**Friends**

[image]

And ID1 and ID2 are IDs (they are not the same) in the ID column of Highschooler. How can I select grades for both of these columns so I have something like:

```
ID1   Grade    ID2   Grade
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `join` `Friends` with `Highschooler` two times (for each `ID` column)

```
select t1.ID1
     , t2.grade
     , t1.ID2
     , t3.grade
from Friends t1 
join Highschooler t2 on t1.ID1 = t2.ID 
join Highschooler t3 on t1.ID2 = t3.ID
```